# Embed DocuSign in my application

Tags: api, docusignapi

We want to integrate embed sending and signing from my application to the point that users of my app don’t know that they are leveraging a mashup?  I want to that my users able to use Signatures without leaving my site. 
I am using API call through Java Code but it is not possible to us send the document and get back it into onesession. Kindly give some code which help me to implement that.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please follow the Stack Overflow guidelines for asking a good question: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

See the DocuSign API recipes:

- [Embedded Sending](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/tag-and-send-workflow-from-your-app) Or use the API directly to enable your app's users to send a signing request. Eg, see the sending step within the [Embedded Signing](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/signing-from-your-app) recipe.
- [Embedded Signing](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/signing-from-your-app)

Comment: I saw that Embedded Signing recipe but there is no any class define and there is not any place to give my credential for login.

Comment: Checkout the entire recipe in GitHub and you should see where you supply your credentials and the signer's information.